What is the correct way to cut a groove in a curved surface?
First point, I am a beginner.
What is the correct way to cut a groove in a curved surface?
Every time i have done this in the past have created an object duplicate slightly scaled down and added boolean cuts to the outer. I am only 3D printing and this works out fine.
But now I am finding I am getting clashes with numerous booleans so I am guessing this is not the correct way to do it...
I have approx 50 small detail grooves to lay over a spherical surface so dont really want to create topology for each one, is there an easy way to do this for 3D printing?

Hello could you please show a reference image of the kind of object you want to do?

Image added.
Just general cross crossign crooves 1m deep and 1mm wide.
Positioning isnt important, just want to know how to apply l00's of these easily.

Create your shape, cut your slots with the knife tool:

Bevel:

Extrude the faces along their normal:

Clean the topology, it should work:


Thank you, that looks good.
Only part I got stuck on and I know this is a noob question but how do I round corners on the knife cuts? Cant see how to do that

It's just the effect of the Subdivision Surface modifier

Next problem...
No matter what extrusion setting i try I cant make the extrude go inwards to the centre of the sphere.
Is there another way to do this?

Alt E > Extrude Faces Along Normals should work, no?

With some tweaking of the face positions I can get it to work, thanks.
But , are there any other ways of applying grooves?

This is not going to work...
I am spending hours on each groove as there are so many points to correct with every action, its becoming a mess and I have hundreds of these grooves to apply.
Is there another way ?
I dont need full topology, I am only 3D printing.
